# Can or could, which is correct, or at least better? Why?

Tags: clauses

She has forgotten how she could open the window. 
Vs 
She has forgotten how she can open the window?

In a sentence like this, which is correct or better ? could  or can? Why?
Thanks!

Comment: It strikes me that I wouldn't say either. She's forgotten *how to* open the window. Or even the middle construction, she's forgotten how the window opens. "But she forgot how she can" sounds like a word-for-word translation from some other tongue.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I should have made it clearer. The point is about the tense. To make the point clearer, Let's take the sentence you said as a example: She has forgotten how the window opens vs She has forgotten how the window opened. Opens or opened, which is correct?

Comment: The method of opening the window is the same now as it was in the past, so the present tense - _how the window opens_ - is correct.